# Which search engine for big data

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, solr, bigdata, talend

Which solutions do you preconize to create an internal google for a company that has different apps with different technologies? 
[image]

Comment: Large companies typically use Splunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use opensource search engine like solr & elasticsearch. They provide the data importhandlers that could read the data from SQL databases, it could also ingest pdf, images, etc. Sometimes the ingest the data you might have to write the custom solutions like scripts, you could use Java/Python API to connect to solr and perform the reading and writing operation.

If you like to go for paid I will recommend using the Lucidworks, they have various connectors to read data from files, hadoop, github, DB's etc you could also place crons in that.

All the above solutions could provide you big data search and you will be able to get the relevant results out of it within fraction of milliseconds.

I hope it helps, if you specific question please let me know!

Comment: Couldn't agree more! No need to reinvent the wheel.